# Canonical metric of toric Kahler manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be non-compact toric Kahler manifold associated to a Delzant polygon $P$

and $g$ be the canonical Kahler metric constructed by Guillemin. Is it true that

the real part of $g$, as a Riemannian metric on $X$, is always a complete Riemannian metric

(Here $X$ is noncompact)? Is there an effective way to compute the Riemannian distance

function of toric manifolds?

Comment: At least this is true in the case when your toric manifold is covered by $\mathbb{C}^n$ charts. This is the case for many examples, say $K_S$, the canonical bundle of any toric manifold $S$, or $\mathbb{C}^n$ blown up at the origin, or $\mathscr{O}(-1)\oplus\mathscr{O}(-1)\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: If you further assume you toric manifold is affine, then you only get trivial examples like $\mathbb{C}^n\times(\mathbb{C}^\ast)^m$, these are of course also complete.